# Не устанавливается обязательная связь элементов таблиц Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity

Выскакивает исключение, которое говорит о том что нет звязи элементов, хотя на диаграмме в sql она вроде есть

```
internal class Books
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int AuthorsID { get; set; }
        public virtual Library library{ get; set; }
    }

internal class Library
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Style { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Books> Books { get; set; }
    }

internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext() : base("DbConnectionString")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Library> Libraries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Books> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

И сама программа, которая добавляет элементы в таблицу и выводит инфу в консоль

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
            {
                var author = new Library()
                {
                    Name = "Gogol",
                    Style = "Horror"
                };
                

                var author2 = new Library()
                {
                    Name = "Puskkin"
                };
                context.Libraries.Add(author);
                context.Libraries.Add(author2);
                context.SaveChanges();

                var books = new List<Books>()
                {
                    new Books() { Name = "Viy", AuthorsID = author.Id},
                    new Books() { Name ="Evgeniy Onegin", AuthorsID = author2.Id}
                };
                context.Books.AddRange(books);
                context.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var book in books) {


                    Console.WriteLine($" Book name = {book.Name}, Authors name = {book.library.Name}");
                }
```

И когда я пытаюсь вывести автора книги `{book.library.Name}` вылезает исключение

Comment: Какое именно исключение? NRE?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: Ну, всё верно. Так вы создаёте объекты: `new Books() { Name = "Viy", AuthorsID = author.Id}`. Свойство `library` не задано, т. е. равно `null`.

Comment: Кстати, к Entity Framework ошибка не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Я вроде задал свойство в классе Books. Просто не понимаю как мне реализовать получения имя author  класса Library через связь идентификатора author  и свойства AuthorsID объекта класса books?

Comment: `context.Entry(book).Reference(x => x.library).Load()` и у вас загрузится `library`

Comment: iiKuzmychov, я так  понял context.Entry(book).Reference(x => x.library).Load() в цикл надо вставлять? Так ничего не измелилось. Пробовал переставлять и менять значения - всё без толку.

Comment: Я по идее через свойство library должен получать значение Name, но оно возвращает мне Null.

Comment: странно, и к слову, если вы хотите кого-то упомянуть, добавляйте перед никнеймом @, без неё я о вашем упоминании вряд-ли узнаю

Comment: а ну и мой код не работает, наверное, потому, что вы забыли связать ключ с сущностью. Добавьте `[ForeignKey(nameof(library))]` перед `public int AuthorsID { get; set; }`, сделайте новую миграцию и примените её

Answer (score 0):

В модели Books свойство AuthorsID не нужно

В своем примере я кое что переименовал)

```
        internal class Book
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
        }

        internal class Author
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Style { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
        }

        internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public MyDbContext() : base("DbConnectionString")
            {
                
            }
            public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        }




        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var author = new Author()
            {
                Name = "Gogol",
                Style = "Horror"
            };


            var author2 = new Author()
            {
                Name = "Puskkin"
            };
            context.Authors.Add(author);
            context.Authors.Add(author2);
            var books = new List<Book>()
            {
                new Book() { Name = "Viy", Author = author},
                new Book() { Name ="Evgeniy Onegin", Author = author2}
            };
            context.Books.AddRange(books);
            context.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var book in books)
            {


                Console.WriteLine($" Book name = {book.Name}, Authors name = {book.Author.Name}");

            }
        }
```